# Atom Editor theme change the color of character pointer

Tags: css, atom-editor

Hello guys I have 2 questions.

1. How can I change the color of the character pointer in Atom?

[image]

2. When I use the find function atom highlight all the words that match my query in grey that is to hard to see... How can I change the color??

Comment: atom? what is it? actual atom or editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do this in Atom. Navigate to `styles.less` through *File > Open Your Stylesheet*. At the bottom of this file, there will be this code

```
atom-text-editor::shadow .cursor {

}
```

This is the code for the cursor color. You can change the color by doing

```
border-color: //your color here; (yellow stands out well against the darker background)
```

inside the the brackets.

Comment: The shadow DOM has been deprecated in Atom since v1.13.0. Anyone looking to do this now should use `atom-text-editor .cursor { ... }` as the selector.

Comment: can i also modify the size of the cursor to be for exampe `half of a block cursor` using this `shadow` option?